# Mathematical Induction getting the right side

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, fractions

So I 've been doing Mathematical Inductions but I seem to have a issue in simplify and getting the right side.

So I have this on the L.H.S
$$\frac{k(k + 1)(2k +1)}{6} + (k + 1)^2 $$

And I'm trying to make it equal to 
$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$

I've check the book for help but for this it seems to be skipping some steps.

And I might as well post this as well which I had the same issue as above.

$$\frac{3(5^{k+1} −1)}{4}+ 3·5^{k+1}$$
to
$$\frac{3(5^{k+2} −1)}{4}.$$

Comment: For the first, start by bringing to a common denominator. Then "take out" a common factor of $k+1$. Now you will be closer. The  second as it is currently written will not work, the expressions are not equal, there may be a mistake earlier.

Comment: With the editing of the second, things are OK. Bring to a common denominator $4$. You will have numerator $(3)(5^{k+1})-3+(4)(3)(5^{k+1})$, which is $(15)(5^{k+1})-3$, which is $(3)(5^{k+2})-3$.

Answer (score 1):

(1)$\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + (k+1)^2 =\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1) + 6(k+1)^2}{6} =
(k+1)\frac{k(2k+1)+6(k+1)}{6} = (k+1)\frac{k(2k+1)+6k+6}{6} = (k+1)\frac{2k^2 + 7k + 6}{6} = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6} $

(2)  Is your second statement even true? for $k=1$ I get: $34 = 93$...

Let $5^k = x$

$\frac{3(5x-1)}{4} + 3x + 1 = \frac{15x - 3 + 12x + 4}{4} = \frac{27x+1}{4}$

which doesn't seem to be equal to your given RHS

Comment: the second got mess up during editing it was  3(5^k+1)/4 + 3*5^k+1

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6} + (k+1)^2$$

Let us get the part of this expression on the right side to have a common denominator with the fraction, let us use $6$. We now have:
$$\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + \frac{6(k+1)^2}{6}$$
$$=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)+6(k+1)^2}{6} $$
Factoring out a $(k+1)$ from the numerator:
$$=\frac{(k+1)(k(2k+1)+6(k+1))}{6}$$
Expanding the expression inside the parentheses:
$$=\frac{(k+1)(2k^2+k+6k+6)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{(k+1)(2k^2+7k+6)}{6}$$
Now we can factor $2k^2+7k+6$ into $(k+2)(2k+3)$ and we obtain:
=$$ \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$

---

In the second part of your question the two equations are not equal. If you want me to explain how I could simplify the expression into something a little more clean, feel free to comment!

Comment: Yes thank you. And The second question got a mess up during formatting but I've fix that. But I have a quick question during factoring the k from the left side was put into the parentheses (2k+1)+6(k+1) was that due to the factoring?

Comment: Yes it was due to the factoring of the $k+1$ from the numerator. Notice that if you divide $k(k+1)(2k+1)+6(k+1)^2$ by $k+1$ it sort of "removes" the $k+1$ term from the expression and multiplies it on the outside. So we are left with $(k+1)(k(2k+1)+6(k+1))$. So, in short, yes it is due to factoring. @Sam Kohnson

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expressing the RHS as
$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$
I would be inclined to express it as
$$\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)}{6}$$
Similarly, for the LHS, I would prefer to express it in terms of $k+1$ instead of $k$.
$$\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)^2 = \frac{((k+1)-1)(k+1)(2(k+1)-1)}{6}+(k+1)^2$$
Now of that looks a bit messy, try making a substitution, for example $m=k+1$. Then the LHS would become
$$\frac{(m-1)m(2m-1)}{6}+m^2$$
and the RHS becomes
$$\color{blue}{\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}}$$
Continuing with the LHS we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\frac{(m-1)m(2m-1)}{6}+m^2 &=& \displaystyle\frac{(m-1)m(2m-1)}{6}+\frac{6m^2}{6}\\
&=& \displaystyle\frac{(m-1)m(2m-1)}{6}+\frac{6m^2}{6}\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{m}{6}((m-1)(2m-1)+6m)\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{m}{6}(2m^2-3m+1+6m)\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{m}{6}(2m^2+3m+1)\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{m}{6}(2m+1)(m+1)\\
&=&\displaystyle\color{blue}{\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}}\\
\end{array}$$